# Cannon receive SMS messages sending works

Tags: sms, lineageos

I have this error with receiving sms and mms messages on a phone running LineageOS 20. The problem started after a migration from another phone which I think was running a different version of LineageOS (which is what I think caused the problem) I have tried just about everything I can think of and I'm out of ideas. I do think I know what the problem is but everything I have tried to resolve it has failed.

First it does look the the phone does actually gets messages. It seems like there is a problem with a database.  When I run `adb logcat` I get the follow output when the text message comes in:

```
03-23 16:44:39.250  2636  3074 I QImsService: ImsRadioIndicationHidl : onIncomingImsSms()
03-23 16:44:39.251  2636  3074 I QImsService: ImsSenderRxr : [UNSL]< UNSOL_INCOMING_IMS_SMS[SUB0]         
03-23 16:44:39.251  2636  3076 I QImsService: ImsSmsHandler : Message received: what = 2                                                                                              
03-23 16:44:39.251  2636  3076 I QImsService: ImsSmsImpl : onSmsReceived:: token:8 incomingSms:{ mFormat = 3gpp verstat = 0}
03-23 16:44:39.267  2741  2863 W MmsSmsDatabaseHelper: Downgrading database from version 83 to 67.
03-23 16:44:39.272  2636  3073 I QImsService: ImsSmsImpl : acknowledgeSms:: token:8 msgRef:0 result:2         
03-23 16:44:39.272  2636  3073 I QImsService: ImsSenderRxr : acknowledgeSms: messageRef: 0 result: 2
03-23 16:44:39.272  2636  3073 I QImsService: ImsSenderRxr : [0035]> REQUEST_ACK_IMS_SMS [SUB0]
```

When I do the same on a working phone the line `MmsSmsDatabaseHelper: Downgrading database from version 83 to 67.` is not there. So I went on the assumption that the problem is with the sms database. I focused on fixing this by deleting the mmssms.db file, running vacuum; on the database, and copying another mmsms.db from another phone. None of which worked. The other difference is that on the working phone `QImsService: ImsSmsImpl` and `QImsService: ImsSenderRxr` have a result of 1 instead of 2. I assumed this was from the previous database error so I didn't look into it too deeply.

I also took a look at the source code for this in the ASOP repo. The MmsSmsDatabaseHelper.java file had the highest db version of 67. I do now know where the 83 is coming from since I copied the mmssms.db from a working phone. Could the problem be in another database?

I have tried other sms messaging apps when behave the same they can send messages but don't receive with the same logcat output.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated
TIA
Cosmo

Comment: *"LineageOS (which is what I think caused the problem"* - ask LineageOS support

Comment: The database does not match the used app (version). Clear the app data of the used SMS app.

Comment: Are the manufacturers of both phones different? Then it may have different implementations of the SMS databases, thus creating conflict.